# "back on set" meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> I'm fired up about my first day back on set.

I found this sentence in a cartoon movie. I don't understand the second part of it. Good doesn't help.

Comment: Back on *movie set*, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the meaning of the expression [**fired up**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fired-up) as defined by the Macmillan Dictionary:

> feeling very excited about something or impatient to do it

While I couldn't find any reference online for the adverbial **on set** (see [**set construction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_construction) if you want to know what the word *set* actually means), my knowledge of the English language tells me that it should be something relating to the rehearsing of a play or the making of a film (see the adjective [**on-set**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on-set)). In other words, something that's happening on set is happening during the time when a movie or a TV show is being made.

So, **my first day back on set** then means that I've been away from work for some time and now I'm back making whatever movie or TV show that I was in the process of making (probably as an actor or actress) and it's my first day after this long vacation.

Here's a picture of a movie set (or [**a film set**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/film-set) if you're in the UK) if you're still wondering what it actually is:

[image]

Comment: Wow! It totally matches the context of the cartoon movie. Yes, he was an actor who said this sentence. Thank you, :)